# Raspbian: Lock (but not logout) of Command-line-only system so that background processes can continue

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, login, lock

I have a Raspberry pi running full Buster but only boots to command line interface (CLI).  Currently, I can only login or log out.  I want to be able to stay logged in so my background processes can keep running, but lock the system so that someone can't walk up and accidentally mess with it.  I would also like to enable auto-login so certain scripts requiring a logged in user can run, but still have the security of a lock.

This question has nothing to do with SSH anymore and thus the 10 year old SSH thread a moderator recommended is neither partially or wholly duplicative.

Comment: tmux and screen require a user to be logged in first to initiate it as far as I can tell.  I would like to know more about that.  This would make it unsuitable if I want to boot into a logged in but locked state.  I can amend the question as such.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`vlock` is what you are looking for.

I have never used it before, but I just tested it on Kubuntu and it locked the console and the processes running in the background continued to run.

From [die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vlock):

> vlock is a program to lock one or more sessions on the Linux console. This is especially useful for Linux machines which have multiple users with access to the console. One user may lock his or her session(s) while still allowing other users to use the system on other virtual consoles. If desired, the entire console may be locked and virtual console switching disabled.

It does appear to be in the Debian repositories, so you can install it with:

```
$ sudo apt install vlock
```

If for some reason it is not, you can build it from source:

- https://github.com/WorMzy/vlock
- https://github.com/viric/vlock